# An error ocurred when installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

When I desire to install tensorflow by use the command "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow", then an error occurred :

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\canned\\linear_optimizer\\python\\utils\\__pycache__\\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc'
```

How to solve this problem?  please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your question and i want to answer your question is my answer solve your question then i will be really happy with that.

Basically this is an environment issue so that's why i give you some information when you installing your tensor flow environment in your system.

**System requirements**

pip 19.0 or later (requires many Linux 2010 support)
   Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit) 
   mac OS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support)
   Windows 7 or later (64-bit) (Python 3 only) Raspbian 9.0 or later

**Hardware requirements**

Starting with Tensor Flow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPU.
Read the GPU support guide to set up a CUDA -enabled GPU card on Ubuntu or Windows.

**Install the Python development environment on your system**
Requires Python > 3.4 and pip >= 19.0

- python 3 --version
- pip3 --version
- virtualenv --version
  If these packages are already installed, skip to the next step.
  Otherwise, install Python, the pip package manager, and Virtualenv:
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install python 3-dev python 3-pip
- sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv  # system-wide install

Caution: Upgrading the system pip can cause problems
If not in a virtual environment, use python 3 -m pip for the commands below. This ensures that you upgrade and use the Python pip instead of the system pip.

Create a virtual environment (recommended)
Python virtual environments are used to isolate package installation from the system.

Create a new virtual environment by choosing a Python interpreter and making a ./venv directory to hold it:

virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python 3 ./venv
Activate the virtual environment using a shell-specific command:
source ./venv/bin/activate  # sh, bash, ksh, or zsh
When virtualenv is active, your shell prompt is prefixed with (venv).

Install packages within a virtual environment without affecting the host system setup. Start by upgrading pip:
pip install --upgrade pip

pip list  # show packages installed within the virtual environment

And to exit virtualenv later:
deactivate  # don't exit until you're done using Tensor Flow

**Install the Tensor Flow pip package**
Choose one of the following Tensor Flow packages to install from PyPI:

tensor flow —Latest stable release (2.x) for CPU-only (recommended for beginners).
tensor flow-GPU —Latest stable release with GPU support (Ubuntu and Windows).
tf-nightly —Preview build (unstable). Ubuntu and Windows include GPU support.
tensor flow==1.15 —The final version of Tensor Flow 1.x.

Package dependencies are automatically installed. These are listed in the setup.py file under REQUIRED_PACKAGES.

pip install --upgrade tensor flow

## python -c "import tensor flow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

Answer (score 0):

System requirements

pip 19.0 or later (requires many Linux 2010 support) Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit) mac OS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support) Windows 7 or later (64-bit) (Python 3 only) Raspbian 9.0 or later

Hardware requirements

Starting with Tensor Flow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPU. Read the GPU support guide to set up a CUDA -enabled GPU card on Ubuntu or Windows.

Install the Python development environment on your system 
Requires Python > 3.4 and pip >= 19.0

python 3 --version
pip3 --version
virtualenv --version If these packages are already installed, skip to the next step. Otherwise, install Python, the pip package manager, and Virtualenv:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python 3-dev python 3-pip
sudo pip3 install -U virtualenv # system-wide install

Install packages within a virtual environment without affecting the host system setup. Start by upgrading pip: pip install --upgrade pip

Install the Tensor Flow pip package Choose one of the following Tensor Flow packages to install from PyPI:

tensor flow —Latest stable release (2.x) for CPU-only (recommended for beginners). tensor flow-GPU —Latest stable release with GPU support (Ubuntu and Windows). tf-nightly —Preview build (unstable). Ubuntu and Windows include GPU support. tensor flow==1.15 —The final version of Tensor Flow 1.x.

Package dependencies are automatically installed. These are listed in the setup.py file under REQUIRED_PACKAGES.

pip install --upgrade tensor flow